# How do I modify my code in Python

Tags: python, udp, ping, python-3.5

I am working with a UDP Pinger Lab

This is the full question in the instructions:

> Currently, the program calculates the round-trip time for each packet and prints it out individually. Modify this to correspond to the way the standard ping program works. You will need to report the minimum, maximum, and average RTTs at the end of all pings from the client. In addition, calculate the packet loss rate (in percentage).

Before working on this part, I had to create a Client Python code that went with a Server code given to me.

Here is the server code that was given to me:

```
import random
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

serverSocket.bind(('', 12000))

while True:

    rand = random.randint(0, 10)

    message, address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)

    message = message.upper()

    if rand < 4:
        continue
    serverSocket.sendto(message, address)
```

This is my client code which works in a command prompt:

```
import socket 
import time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
server_addr = ('localhost', 12000) 
sock.settimeout(1) 

try: 
    for i in range(1, 11): 
        start = time.time() 
    message = 'Ping #' + str(i) + " " + time.ctime(start) 
    try: 
        sent = sock.sendto(message.encode(), server_addr) 
        print("Sent " + message) 
        data, server = sock.recvfrom(1024) 
        print("Received " + data.decode()) 
        end = time.time(); 
        elapsed = end - start 
        print("RTT: " + str(elapsed) + " seconds\n") 

    except socket.timeout: 
        print("#" + str(i) + " Requested Timed Out\n")

finally: 
    print("closing socket") 
    sock.close()
```

Comment: 1) 50% of the time, the server sends no response. 2) your `for i in range(1, 11)` is not doing what you think it's doing. It's only setting start 10 times in a row.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This looks like homework to me. Review [ask], [how to ask homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3579910) & show us what you've tried.

Comment: to get `minimum` and `maximum` you need variable to keep this value and compare with `elapsed` and update `minimum` and `maximum`. Or you can keep all `elapsed` on list and get `min()`, `max()` at the end. To  calculate the packet loss rate you have to count how many packages you send and how many packages you received.

Comment: printing takes some time so better do `start=..`, `sendto()`, `recvfrom`, `end=...` and later create message and print results.